# Add a parent element to different XML sibling with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a question about XSLT 2.0. I am in a situation like that:

```
<config>
    <!-- elements that needs to be copied as they are -->
    <a>
        <childA attr="attr">text</childA>
    </a>
    <b>
        <childB attrb="attr">text B</childB>
    </b>
    <c>
        <childC attrc="attr">text</childC>
    </c>
</config>
```

and I would like to have this:

```
<config>
    <!-- elements that needs to be copied as they are -->
    <parent>
        <a>
            <childA attr="attr">text</childA>
        </a>
        <b>
            <childB attrb="attr">text B</childB>
        </b>
        <C>
            <childC attrc="attr">text</childC>
        </c>
    </parent>
</config>
```

I made many attempts but they were all basically wrong, I also tried to use for-each-group but definitely I don't think that is the way... Can you please give me some hint on how to/where to look for?

Thank you so much!

Comment: What does the comment refer to, the elements you want to wrap but otherwise not change? Or other elements? How do you identify the ones you want to wrap?

Comment: Hi Martin, Thank you for your question. The comment refers to elements that I don't want to touch, they have to be copied as they are. I know that I want to wrap the elements "a","b","c". The child of these elements have to copied as they are. Moreover, I know that  "a","b","c" appear sequentially in the original xml and "c" is actually the last element of the original XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a template for `config`

```
<xsl:template match="config">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="* except (a, b, c)"/>
     <parent>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="a, b, c"/>
     </parent>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

together with the identity transformation as the starting point (i.e. `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` or the same spelled out as a template).

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="config">
    <xsl:copy>
        <parent>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        </parent>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```